# Develop GJS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnome, gjs

When working with GJS there does not seem to be any documentation.
Is there an integration for Visual Studio Code, at least?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few TypeScript definitions available for GJS:

- Evan Welsh's [gi.ts](https://gitlab.gnome.org/ewlsh/gi.ts)
- sammydre's [ts-for-gjs](https://github.com/sammydre/ts-for-gjs)

The GNOME APIs are documented at https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/. There is also usage documentation and examples in the GJS repository:

- [GObject Usage](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/doc/Mapping.md)
- [Bundled Modules](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/blob/master/doc/Modules.md)
- [Code Examples](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/tree/master/examples)